# Update Display Brightness on Android after changing it programmatically

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I'm trying to update the display brightness from a widget but i have some problems.

To change brightness level, i use:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 200);
```

This modifies the display setting (in fact in Display->Brightness the level is correct) but the effective brightness of display is not changed. If i lock the screen and unlock, the brightness finally changes to the value i set.

I assume this is a Settings Update issue, so how can the display settings be immediatly updated after settings change?

I read that `WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();` should be used but I am working in a App Widget so getWindow() cannot be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue and just created an Activity with no UI to do the brightness change, used an intent to run it from the App Widget.

Comment: Good idea! You created a new class Activity or bound it inside the widget?

Comment: Since you resolved the issue, can you write down some code to explain clearly? Thanks GeekYouUp!

Comment: I tried to create an activity, but the change of brightness is applied to the activity only...

Comment: Hi. Must be some time difference between us, but I'm back now. My brightness setting project is open source the code is at http://autobright.googlecode.com I always need a 500ms wait before finishing the Activity if I want the brightness to be displayed across the system.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure this out this way, I'll let you know!

Comment: @GeekYouUp How can i create dummy activity??

Comment: @Mariux How to make dummy activity as GeekYouUp said.

Comment: @GeekYouUp How to change brightness in Service while I'm using another application?

Answer (score 1):

First, the value to modify in LayoutParams is [screenBrightness](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness). You'll then have to do a [window.setAttributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setAttributes(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams)) to apply it. As [GeekYouUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366255/update-display-brightness-on-android-after-changing-it-programmatically/4366373#4366373) said, you can make a dummy activity to get your Window object.

Comment: How can i create dummy activity??

Comment: as he said, you create an activity, just associated to no UI

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code in  your RemoteView,

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);

// This makes the new screen brightness effective
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getAttributes();
float b = brightness/255.0f;
if(b == 0.0)    
    b = 0.01f;
layoutParams.screenBrightness = b;
((Activity)context).getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

This code fine works when you are setting phone screen brightness from inside a User-defined class which is ***not extending an Activity*** but you only need the context.