# Alter system brightness within a service

Tags: android, service, brightness

Although I am able to set the system brightness within an Activity successfully, it would seem that services don't fair too well. The brightness setting IS being set (I read it back and printed it to Logcat), but the brightness itself is not changing. My issue is very similar to this one:

[Control screen brightness in android using " Background Service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222146/control-screen-brightness-in-android-using-background-service)

However, I'm not happy with the crude nature of the solution offered in that link. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Got a solution! GeekYouUp's method here works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366255/update-display-brightness-on-android-after-changing-it-programmatically

You need to make sure you finish() the activity with a delay, that was my main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution! GeekYouUp's method here works: [Update Display Brightness on Android after changing it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366255/update-display-brightness-on-android-after-changing-it-programmatically)

You need to make sure you finish() the activity with a small delay, that was my main issue. Sure it's not 'clean' to have a transparent activity pop up, but what can you do? I'm quite sure that there's no other way.